# Inequality involving maximums

Tags: real-analysis

I need some hints for proving the following fact about maximums which I know it is true for all real numbers $a$ and $b$.

Prove that $|\max\{a, b\}|\leq\max\{|a|,|b|\}$ for all real numbers $a$ and $b$. I only need hints, not answers.

Comment: This will be hard to prove. Try $a=0, b=-1$.

Comment: Yes, I tried it out with some numerical values and it seems to be true. What I need is an hint so that I approach this proof algebraically. Do you have any suggestions? I will apreciate your help. :)

Comment: What copper is saying is that it's _flat-out_ false.

Comment: Sorry, I may have gave you the wrong statement! I will edit my post so that you can see the real one.

Comment: I already editted the post. Now that's the statement I was trying to show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\max(a,b) \leq \max(|a|,|b|)$, and $|\max(a,b)| = sgn(\max(a,b)) \max(a,b)$. It should be easy from here on.

Answer (score 1):

We have $|\max\{a, b\}|=|a|$ or $|\max\{a, b\}|=|b|$. In both cases we get the desired inequality.

Comment: What cases did you considered there?

Comment: Case 1: $|\max\{a, b\}|=|a|$. Case 2: $|\max\{a, b\}|=|b|$.